# Raw query to cursor statement in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a set of raw queries that I want to transform into `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` and then fetch their data through the cursor() method. For example:

```php
$queries = [];
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from users';
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from toys INNER JOIN users ON toys.owner_id = user.id';
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from toys';

$connection = \DB::connection();

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $builder = $connection->query();
    // Pass some how the raw query to the builder
    $builder->raw($query);
    // Execute the statement with a cursor function
    foreach($builder->cursor() as $data) {
         // Do something
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is on how to pass the raw query to the Builder and then fetch the data trought the cursor method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You can just use `DB::select($query)` and it returns an array of rows, doesn't it?

Comment: Cursor is more memory efficient: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors that's why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the official API documentation](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_cursor) you should be able to use `cursor()` just like `select()`.

```
$generator = DB::cursor('SELECT * from users'); 

foreach ($generator as $data) { ... }
```

```
$queries = [];
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from users';
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from toys INNER JOIN users ON toys.owner_id = user.id';
$queries[] = 'SELECT * from toys';

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    foreach(\DB::cursor($query) as $data) {
         // Do something
    }
}
```

`\DB::connection()->cursor($query)` is the same as `\DB::cursor($query)`. Through the magic method `__call`, the `DatabaseManager` (`DB` Facade) pipes the cursor call to the default connection.

Comment: This just changed my life!